# Unable to get gremlin scala predicate to work

Tags: scala, graph-databases, gremlin

I am not able to run the example from the gremlin scala site that uses Scala Gremlin Predicates

Below is the complete code and error message

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph

val graph = TinkerFactory.createModern.asScala

val Created = "created"

val v1Label = StepLabel[Vertex]()
graph.V(1).out(Created).as(v1Label).in(Created).where(P.neq(v1Label.name)).toList()
```

Error:

> error: value neq is not a member of object gremlin.scala.P
>          graph.V(1).out(Created).as(v1Label).in(Created).where(P.neq(v1Label.name)).toList()

Comment: which version of gremlin-scala did you use? I just tried with 3.3.0.2 and it works just fine. Here's the code, it's been there since April 2017: https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/0284df06896f6fc96218b6de29fbf40095fde336/gremlin-scala/src/main/scala/gremlin/scala/P.scala#L11

Comment: That was it. I was using a previous version 3.2.5.1. Switched and it worked. Thank you for all your work. Much appreciated !

Comment: great! you can mark your question as 'answered' then

Answer (score 0):

Still could not get it to work with Scala Predicates but you can use Java predicates instead

```
graph.V(1).out(Created).as("a").in(Created).where(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.P.neq("a")).toList()
```

Comment: This is still a hack. Ideally, would like to use Scala, and step label vertex. Code was sourced from : https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/master/gremlin-scala/src/test/scala/gremlin/scala/TraversalSpec.scala